# Cross-domain templating with Javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, media-player, templating, same-origin-policy

I'm currently building a Javascript library that can be used to easily create embeddable media based on the URL of a media file, and then be controlled using Javascript methods and events (think something like the Flash / Silverlight [JW player](http://longtailvideo.com/)).

Of course, i could simply cat all the html tags from the Javascript library and send that to the browser:

```
function player(url) {
    document.write('<object type="foo"><param name="something" value="bar">' + 
    <param name="source" value=" + url + '/></object>');
}
```

But i think this is a very ugly practice that tends to create unmanageable code that is unreadable when you review it a few weeks later.

So, a templating solution seems to be the way to go. I've been looking to [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/) because it loads the templates using AJAX, so you can manage your templates in separate file instead of directly on the HTML page.

There's one 'gotcha' with that: my library needs to be completely cross-domain: the library itself could be located on foo.com while the serving site could be located on bar.com. So if bar.com would want to add a media player using the library it needs to do an AJAX call to a template located on foo.com, which won't work because of the same-origin policy in browsers.

AFAIK, there's no library that uses something like JSONP to read and write templates to get around this problem.

Could anyone point me to a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question: you need some kind of server-side solution that delivers JSONP to solve this problem. Let's say tou have a template on server foo.com, you could have a server-side script that answers to requests like these:

```
http://foo.com/template/bar.html?callback=cb
```

Which would return:

```
cb({
    "html" : "<p>i'm a template!</p>"
});
```

Then you can use any template language you want and parse the template in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this question, but I've come to believe that KnockOut JS is the best solution for third-party template rendering. If you are loading your JS onto a third-party's web pages, Knockout lets you very easily inject your data into their DOM, without having to hold the entire section of HTML as a template which you "render" (this is the paradigm that moustache and similar use).

The code is simple - here's the third party's web page region you want to template:

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
```

After loading knockout js library itself, you then just present some data to knockout as a javascript "data model object" and it does the rest:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

References:

- http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html
- http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro